# woocommerce - hide specific variation in certain category

Tags: woocommerce, display, product-variations

I Have my products in 2 categories:

- the first with one price (like a simple product): "Distributeur" (vending machine)
- and the other "A emporter" (shop) with 3 variations (S, M, XL).

Some of the products are in the vending machine and in the shop. But the prices or sizes are different.

For example "My pizza X":

- in the vending: Size M only at 9$
- in the shop: Size S at 6$, Size M at 8$ and size XL at 17$

So on my product page, I wish to display only "the Size M at 9$" if the current category is the vending machine and hide the other variations, or display the shop variation (S, M, XL) if the current category is the shop and hide "the Size M at 9$ variation"

I'm using WC Variations Radio Buttons to display them (so it's checkboxes not options select).

I tried to use the top product category to create a CSS rule like this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 *
 * Modified to use radio buttons instead of dropdowns
 * @author 8manos
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );



do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); 


$cat = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ($cat as $topcat) {
    if($topcat->parent == 0){
      $slugTop = $topcat->slug;
    }
}



 ?>
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( wp_json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr class="attribute-<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>">
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
                        <?php
                        $sanitized_name = sanitize_title( $name );
                        if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $sanitized_name ] ) ) {
                            $checked_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $sanitized_name ];
                        } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ $sanitized_name ] ) ) {
                            $checked_value = $selected_attributes[ $sanitized_name ];
                        } else {
                            $checked_value = '';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <td class="value <?php echo $slugTop; ?>">
                            <?php
                            if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
                                if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {
                                    // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                                    $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        print_attribute_radio( $checked_value, $term->slug, $term->name, $sanitized_name );
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                                        print_attribute_radio( $checked_value, $option, $option, $sanitized_name );
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

and did this in my css:

```
td.value.produits-a-emporter div:last-child{
            display:none !important;
        }
td.value.distributeur div:first-child, td.value.distributeur div:nth-child(2), td.value.distributeur div:nth-child(3){
            display:none !important;
        }
```

but it still displaying

Someone knows how to edit my code to make it work?

Comment: I just edit my post with the entire code.

Actually there are category: "distributeur": it's a vending machine. My clients solding pizzas in specific size with specific prices

But he is solding the same products in his shop ("a-emporter" slug) with a different prices and sizes. 

for exemple:
in the vending: size M at 9$
in the shop: SIZE S at 6$, SIZE M at 8$, SIZE XL at 16$

So I wish on the product display the vending machine price or shop prices/variations depending of the category

Comment: Thank you I just contact you on messenger :)

Comment: So you should better remove this question as it's not possible.